# Temporarily redirect pages to a section of a landing page?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, 302-redirect, single-page-application

I have created a single page landing page while I redesign my website that has sections for popular pages. So the landing page has an events section, location section, contact section etc. How do I temporarily redirect those pages from my old site to the temporary sections without losing any SEO juice on those pages when I want to 301 them to the new pages? I've looked at using "hashbangs(#!)", canonical tags and using pushstate() but none of those seem to solve my issue.

Comment: 302 temporary redirect?

Comment: Redirects are enough. The other things you mentioned do not apply. @w3dk is right about using a 302 if it is just temporary. A 301 redirect is permanent.

Comment: It will be a 302 redirect to the temporary landing page(ideally to each section) and then a 301 to the permanent page upon website redesign completion.

Comment: Right ok, so what's the question?

Comment: If I 302 redirect mysite.com/services to mynewsite.com#services, are the Google bots smart enough to figure out that I'm not redirecting all my pages to mynewsite.com.

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your question that you are keeping your site content but making a new structure for it. This is fine, and good. But it is not something that should be attempted with tricks.

Rather I would do a most simple 2 step process:

1) Get a robots.txt and ["/" disallow your full site (see also the other steps lower) and then in Google Search Console TELL GOOGLE TO REMOVE YOUR FULL SITE from view.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en)
2) When ready to re-index your site do so again in Search Console.

**GOOGLE STATES:**

> The Remove URLs tool is only a temporary
>   removal. To remove content or a URL from Google search permanently you
>   must take one or more of the following additional actions:
>
> Remove or update the actual content from your site (images, pages,
>   directories) and make sure that your web server returns either a 404
>   (Not Found) or 410 (Gone) HTTP status code. Non-HTML files (like PDFs)
>   should be completely removed from your server. (Learn more about HTTP
>   status codes) Block access to the content, for example by requiring a
>   password. Indicate that the page should not to be indexed using the
>   noindex meta tag. This is less secure than the other methods. ([Via](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en#make-permanent))

Comment: Re-include content in search see: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/59833?hl=en&ref_topic=1724262

"Content removed via the Remove URLs page will not appear in search results for a minimum of 90 days.

To reinclude content at any time during the 90-day period:
From the Search Console Home page, click the site you want.
In the left-hand menu, navigate to Google Index > Remove URLs.
Select the Removed content tab
Click Reinclude next to the content you want to reinclude in Google Search results."